# MySQL - autoincrement to guid

Tags: mysql, guid, auto-increment

I have a table with an auto-increment ID field as shown below.

```
+------------+-------------------------------------+
| company_id | name                                |
+------------+-------------------------------------+
|          1 | International Client                |
|          2 | Oracle                              |
|          3 | test                                |
|          4 | testabc                             |
|          5 | testdef                             |
|          6 | abcd                                |
+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

I want to update the ID column to be a GUID using the

```
uuid()
```

function.

Additionally, how do I update the foreign key references to the correct GUID?

Answer (score 9):

Use triggers.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_test` (
  `GUID` char(40) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`GUID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

table and pk, now trigger..

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER `t_GUID` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_test`
 FOR EACH ROW begin
 SET new.GUID = uuid();
end//
DELIMITER ;
```

Now try,

```
insert into tbl_test(Name) value('trigger happy...');
```

regards,
/t

Comment: That's fine. But there are tables with `GUID` as foreign key. How do I update those as the master table is updated?

Comment: (master table = PK?) why would you change the PK once set?

Comment: If you wish to add an auto-time/date stamp for 'creation of data', this worked adding this line after the GUID line: `Created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

Comment: @Teson -  Does not work for me. ALL records are created with the same GUID.

Comment: @DuckDucking , sounds strange. Quick google says you may suffer a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58600623/mysql-uuid-function-produces-the-same-value-when-used-as-a-function-parameter

Comment: @Teson, this is what I am suspecting. .THANKS

Answer (score 4):

you can't use it with autoincrement

guid is char not intger

you need to insert it your self

also you will need to change the id to char(40)

```
insert into table_name (id,name) values (uuid(),'jon');
```

Answer (score 3):

In *mysql 8.0* you can use something like below:

**For UUID without dashes:**

```
create table temp (`company_id` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT (REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')), 'name' varchar(100) NOT NULL);
```

**For UUID with dashes:**

```
create table temp (`company_id` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT (UUID()), 'name' varchar(100) NOT NULL);
```

I hope this answers your question, Let me know if it is not or you need more.