# MySQL Workbench Auto-generate UUID for primary key

Tags: mysql

How can I configure my table in MySQL Workbench to auto generate a UUID on INSERT?

I have set the column as VARCHAR(128), PK, NN, G with the default expression as UUID(). When I create a record the ID is 'UUID()'.

How can I get the database to generate UUID's automagically on INSERT? All the examples I see are auto-increment but UUID's are character strings so I can't use auto-increment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - autoincrement to guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230638/mysql-autoincrement-to-guid)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793203/how-can-affect-performance-when-i-use-uuids-as-my-primary-keys-in-mysql if you really want to use UUID as the primary key for your table.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a non-standard DB, like MariaDB, you have to leave the `G` unchecked, use `uuid()` in Default/Expression column and you should be good to go.