# MySQL uuid not creating table

Tags: mysql

trying to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
(
    id          BINARY(16) default (uuid_to_bin(uuid()))
);
```

But it is not working

the error is:

```
[42000][1064] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(uuid_to_bin(uuid())) )' at line 2
```

MySQL version is: 8.0.4

**Any other suggestions on how to generate an uuid v4 in MySQL are welcome**

### What I have tried:

- Upgrade to MySql 8.0.11
- Remove the parenthesis: `uuid_to_bin(uuid())`

### EDIT:

The suggestion comes from here: [How to generate/autoincrement guid on insert without triggers and manual inserts in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61349754/how-to-generate-autoincrement-guid-on-insert-without-triggers-and-manual-inserts)

Comment: v8.0. **13**, not v8.0.11, see my answer to the duplicate question.